# How to read RSS fees on iPod Classic?

Tags: windows-xp, rss, ipod

I am using Windows XP and iPod Classic(120GB).
I want to read RSS feeds on my iPod.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article : [Read RSS feeds on your iPod](http://www.engadget.com/2004/04/16/pts-how-to-fridays-read-rss-feeds-on-your-ipod/).
It it's explained in much detail with screenshots.